Struggling getting the slash commands to sync with discord's built in command helper
I'm working on a discord bot in python using the discord-py library. I want my commands to appear in the command prompt popup window for commands when someone starts typing a slash command. From what I can gather online, there are two current methods to do so. The interactions library or the commands package in discord.ext. To switch to interactions now seems to be a bit of a struggle when looking at it and I am not even certain it would solve my problem. Other than the commands not showing up in the prompt the following code functions all be it not very pretty. What am I missing for the bot to sync properly with the command prompt?
## Import statements
import configparser
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
import typing
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

#Load in config file/config settings
config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
try:
    config.read('config.properties')
except:
    print("Failed to read config.properties - Make sure the file exists")
    exit

#Dataclass of a User which we will store in a queue
@dataclass
class User:
    social_name: str = ""
    alt_name: str = ""
    username: str = ""
    discord_user_id: int = 0

@dataclass
class Queue:
    name: str = ""
    rate: int = 1
    vc_optional: bool = True
    vc_id: int = 0
    users_at_bat: list[User] = field(default_factory=list)
    user_list: list[User] = field(default_factory=list)
    locked: bool = False

ACTIVE_QUEUES = list()

def getActiveQueuesList():
    return [q.name for q in ACTIVE_QUEUES]

def getQueuesString():
    queues = "<Type: None>"
    if len(ACTIVE_QUEUES) > 0:
        queues = ACTIVE_QUEUES[0].name
    if len(ACTIVE_QUEUES) > 1:
        for q in ACTIVE_QUEUES[1::]:
            queues.append(", " + q.name)
    return queues

def insertUserIntoQueue(queueName, user):
    success = False
    for q in ACTIVE_QUEUES:
        if q.name == queueName:
            success = True
            q.user_list.append(user)
    return success

#Starting the discord bot
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".", intents=discord.Intents.all())



@bot.listen('on_ready')
async def on_ready():
    print("Hello! Chromes Py-Bot is ready!")
    channel = bot.get_channel(int(config.get('Discord', 'BOT_LOG_ID')))
    await channel.send("Hello! Chromes Py-Bot is ready!")



@bot.command(
        name="ping",
        description="Ping command"
)
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send("pong!")



@bot.command(
        name="helpme",
        description="not gonna help ya btw"
)
async def helpme(ctx):
    await ctx.send("no")



@bot.command(
        name="getQueues",
        description="Get the queues locked or not"
)
async def getQueues(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"There are {len(ACTIVE_QUEUES)} active queues: {getQueuesString()}")



@bot.command(
        name="createQueue",
        description="it's a little on the nose ik"
)
async def createQueue(ctx, name: str, rate: typing.Optional[int] = 1, vc_id: typing.Optional[int] = 0, vc_optional: typing.Optional[bool] = True):
    if name in getActiveQueuesList():
        await ctx.send(f"Failed to create queue {name} because a queue already exists with that name.")
        return
    queue = Queue(name, rate, vc_optional, vc_id)
    ACTIVE_QUEUES.append(queue)
    await ctx.send(f"Created queue: {queue.name}")



@bot.command(
        name="deleteQueue",
        description="deletes the queue based on the name you put in"
)
async def deleteQueue(ctx, name):
    for q in ACTIVE_QUEUES[::-1]:
        if q.name == name:
            ACTIVE_QUEUES.remove(q)
    await ctx.send(f"There are now {len(ACTIVE_QUEUES)} active queues: {getQueuesString()}")



@bot.command(
        name="joinQueue",
        description="joins the author into the specified queue"
)
async def joinQueue(ctx, queue: str, username: typing.Optional[str] = ""):
    author = ctx.author
    alt_name = ""
    if author.nick is not None:
        alt_name = author.nick
    user = User(author.display_name, alt_name, username, author.id)
    if insertUserIntoQueue(queue, user):
        await ctx.send(str(user) + " added to the queue: " + queue)
    else:
        await ctx.send(str(user) + " failed to be added to the queue: " + queue)



bot.run(config.get('Discord', 'BOT_TOKEN'))


I missed a crucial element when setting the bot up on the discord development portal. When Selecting the scope in the OAuth2 URL Generator, be sure to not only select the bot scope but also the applications.commands.

Just FYI, I also switched from discord-py to py-cord a fork of discord-py which better utilizes the applications.command features which also meant all the @bot.commands switched to @bot.slash_command( ) and instead of ctx.send() i needed to use ctx.respond()
